# How do I limit the list of pages shown on a menu?

Tags: google-app-maker

I've followed the example in the "Starter App".  The menu shows all my pages. However, I only want certain pages to show.  The example uses @pages._values as the data source, but I don't want all pages to show in the menu (some pages are only available under certain circumstances or are called from other pages).

How do I limit the menu datasource to the pages I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the "Starter App" template, first select the "Menu" *PageFragment* and then select the *MenuListRow* widget:

[image]

Then expand the *Display* properties and click on "visible". Next, click on "binding".

[image]

Now, we will use an array to determine what are the pages we want to limit. In this example, the array I'm using is `["Admin", "TestOne"]` and we will use the **indexOf** method to match the page name that the label inside the list row widget contains. The value looks like this `["Admin", "TestOne"].indexOf(@widget.descendants.MenuItem.text) !== -1`

[image]

Now just click "Ok" and then preview the app. The result is the following:

[image]

Please note that in the example I have 6 pages but only the two that are in the array are displayed. I hope this is helpful. If you need further clarification, please let me know.